How would font-size-adjust fix size differences of fallback fonts?
A common motivation behind font-size-adjust seems to be that it would help with the problem where you have fallback fonts that are visually different in size, even with the same font-size.
But how would that work, exactly? All the examples I've seen use different selectors to apply the font-size-adjust. How exactly does that help with anything?
If my h1 has font-family: MySlowlyLoadedWebfont, Arial, sans-serif, and there are size differences between Arial and the webfont, then how would I use font-size-adjust to adjust Arial to the same glyph width as my webfont?

Please add a minimal reproducible example. Have a look at this related post "How can you change the size of a secondary font without changing the size of the fallback (primary) font with css?". Frankly, you should focus on optimizing the font loading times e.g by preferring woff2, using subsets adding preloading etc. Font size adjustments may work but I wouldn't  call it a reliable to avoid all layout shifts.
